# "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" when code is in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a very simple program that randomly selects 2 values from a numbers list, adds them and saves them into a variable and then asks the user to type the correct answer. If the answer is right it prints that its right and if its not it prints that its wrong. The program runs without any problems if its not in a while loop but when its in a while loop and the program asks me for input and I input a value I get this error code:

```
    line 16, in <module>
    input = input(str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + " = ")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Program in while loop where the error occurs:

```py
import random
import os

while True:

    os.system('cls||clear')

    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    num1 = random.choice(numbers)

    num2 = random.choice(numbers)

    answer = num1 + num2

    input = input(str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + " = ")

    if int(input) == answer:
        os.system('cls||clear')
        print("right")
    else:
        os.system('cls||clear')
        print("wrong: " + str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + " " + "=" + " " + str(answer))
```

Program without while loop that runs without problems:

```py
import random
import os

os.system('cls||clear')

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

num1 = random.choice(numbers)

num2 = random.choice(numbers)

answer = num1 + num2

input = input(str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + " = ")

if int(input) == answer:
    os.system('cls||clear')
    print("right")
else:
    os.system('cls||clear')
    print("wrong: " + str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + " " + "=" + " " + str(answer))
```

Comment: Try: *if int(input()) == answer:*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the input() method with the input variable. Change this line:

```
input = input(str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + " = ")
```

into this line:

```
answer = input(str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + " = ")
```

(and update the remaining references to the input variable) and you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

`input = input(...)` runs well the first time, however, this sets the value of the name `input` to the value that was input by the user, which means `input` now is a string and not the `input` function, so a second call (`input(...)`) results in an error saying that you can not treat a string value as a function (call it in this case). It is always advisable to not use built-in names as your own variable names, so you should change the input variable to something else, like `guess = input(...)` or `attempt = input(...)` or something useful based on your context.

Answer (score 0):

Your input variable should not be called input as it is a protected name. Rename it to something like userInput.

Answer (score 0):

You *redefine* `input` to be a string. The second time it's called you try to call a `str` object, which produces the above error. Try renaming your `input`  variable to something else, maybe `answer`?